# Simplify Integrate results

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I wish to simplify the overlap of two gaussian-type orbitals,

```
primGauOrb = ((2 α)/π)^(3/4)E^(-α (x^2 + y^2 + z^2));
```

And then integrate it,

```
Assuming[Element[{xA, yA, zA, xB, yB, zB}, Reals] && α > 0 && β > 0, 
 Integrate[(primGauOrb /. {x -> x - xB, y -> y - yB, 
   z -> z - zB, α -> β})*(primGauOrb /. {x -> x - xA, y -> y - yA, z -> z - zA}), 
   {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]] /. 
{xA^2 - 2*xA*xB + xB^2 + yA^2 - 2*yA*yB + yB^2 + zA^2 - 2*zA*zB + zB^2 -> Norm[RA - RB]^2}
```

Gives me the result,

```
ConditionalExpression[(1/Sqrt[((α+β)^3)])2 Sqrt[2] E^(-((α β Norm[RA-RB]^2)/(α+β))) (α β)^(3/4) Sqrt[-((α+β)/(xA^2 α^2+yA^2 α^2+zA^2 α^2+2 xA xB α β+2 yA yB α β+2 zA zB α β+xB^2 β^2+yB^2 β^2+zB^2 β^2))] Sqrt[-((xA^2 α^2+yA^2 α^2+zA^2 α^2+2 xA xB α β+2 yA yB α β+2 zA zB α β+xB^2 β^2+yB^2 β^2+zB^2 β^2)/(α+β))],(α+β) (xA^2 α^2+yA^2 α^2+zA^2 α^2+2 xA xB α β+2 yA yB α β+2 zA zB α β+xB^2 β^2+yB^2 β^2+zB^2 β^2)<0]
```

This is true, as the right answer is $\frac{2 \sqrt{2} (\alpha  \beta )^{3/4} e^{-\frac{\alpha  \beta  \left\| \text{RA}-\text{RB}\right\| ^2}{\alpha +\beta }}}{\sqrt{(\alpha +\beta )^3}}$, but the condition may always be false.

That is, although $x<0$, $\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}\sqrt{x}$ part should also cancel.

Comment: I want to know what is the _right_ way to do this in mathematica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a rule to simplify it

the `FullSimplify@@expr` can easily deal with the conditional expression.

```
formula=FullSimplify@@ConditionalExpression[(1/Sqrt[((α+β)^3)])2 Sqrt[2] E^(-((α β Norm[RA-RB]^2)/(α+β))) (α β)^(3/4) Sqrt[-((α+β)/(xA^2 α^2+yA^2 α^2+zA^2 α^2+2 xA xB α β+2 yA yB α β+2 zA zB α β+xB^2 β^2+yB^2 β^2+zB^2 β^2))] Sqrt[-((xA^2 α^2+yA^2 α^2+zA^2 α^2+2 xA xB α β+2 yA yB α β+2 zA zB α β+xB^2 β^2+yB^2 β^2+zB^2 β^2)/(α+β))],(α+β) (xA^2 α^2+yA^2 α^2+zA^2 α^2+2 xA xB α β+2 yA yB α β+2 zA zB α β+xB^2 β^2+yB^2 β^2+zB^2 β^2)<0];
((formula//Numerator)/.Sqrt[x_]*Sqrt[y_]:>Sqrt[x y]//FullSimplify)/(formula//Denominator)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is ofter very tricky to make Mathematica simplify a result in a way you desire.

First, let's compute the integral "as is" an see what assumptions Mathematica will use:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
primGauOrb[x_, y_, z_, α_] := ((2 α)/π)^(3/4) E^(-α (x^2 + y^2 + z^2));
Integrate[primGauOrb[x - xB, y - yB, z - zB, β]*
 primGauOrb[x - xA, y - yA, z - zA, α], {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
 {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

So we can use this same assumption to get final output:

```
result=Integrate[primGauOrb[x - xB, y - yB, z - zB, β]*
 primGauOrb[x - xA, y - yA, z - zA, α], {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
 {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> Re[α + β] >= 0]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Now we can make final substitution to represent numerator in exponent in desired form:

```
Simplify[result, (xA^2 - 2 xA xB + xB^2 + yA^2 - 2 yA yB + yB^2 + zA^2 - 2 zA zB + 
 zB^2) == Norm[RA - RB]^2]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Or if you like more traditional form:

```
Format[norm[a_]] := DoubleBracketingBar[a]
Simplify[result, (xA^2 - 2 xA xB + xB^2 + yA^2 - 2 yA yB + yB^2 + zA^2 - 2 zA zB + 
 zB^2) == norm[RA - RB]^2]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Hi Alx, thank you very much for your help. What is the difference between `primGauOrb = ((2 α)/π)^(3/4)E^(-α (x^2 + y^2 + z^2));` and `primGauOrb[x_, y_, z_, α_] := ((2 α)/π)^(3/4) E^(-α (x^2 + y^2 + z^2));` ? In my point of view, the first is a symbolic expression, and the second is a function that takes symbolic variables. Are they different?

Comment: I defined `primGauOrb` as a function to simplify input of integral, to not make those `ReplaceAll` substitutions of `x -> x - xA` etc. If you need to use some expression many times with different internals (`x` etc in this case) it is better to define that as a function.

Comment: I did as what you suggested in your answer, the result can be obtained in this way. But I got some error information. `$Assumptions::cas: Warning: contradictory assumption(s) Re[\[Alpha]+\[Beta]]>0&&\[Alpha]+\[Beta]<0 encountered.` I tried to restart my notebook, but that does not work....

Comment: You probably have some previously setted assumptions, there is no such contradicted in my code as you show. Try with fresh Mathematica session: Evaluation -> Quit Kernel, then run my code, it should work.

Comment: You can also clear previous asuumptions with: `$Assumptions=.`.

Comment: Yes,  I tried to restart the kernel and add `$Assumptions=.`. The warning still exists.

Comment: Save your work and close Mathematica completely. Start Mathematica with new empty notebook, type in `$Assumptions`, the output should be `True`, i.e. there is no predefined assumptions. Then run code in my answer. If the error is stiil there, I don't know what else to do, sorry.

Comment: The problem may come from `Assuming`....`Integrate[(primGauOrb /. {x -> x - xB, y -> y - yB, 
     z -> z - zB, \[Alpha] -> \[Beta]}) (primGauOrb /. {x -> x - xA, 
     y -> y - yA, 
     z -> z - 
       zA}), {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {y, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}, {z, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> Re[\[Alpha] + \[Beta]] > 0]` works....Thank you all the same!

Comment: OK, good that it works and I was able to help!